# How to crop margin in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, margin, crop

I have many images (*.pdf) that originally do not have margin. The files are in various sizes but usually from 8000x4000 to 20000x14000 px.

I use this command to convert them to jpeg:

for /r %x in (*.pdf) do convert -density 400 -quality 100% "%x" "%x.jpg"

But it produces big margins. Margins take 30% of the image size. So I need to prevent them or to crop them. I tried to look in IM manual to find how to obtain width and height and to substract some value and to add it to -crop. But this his too hard to me, I am tring to solve it about 1,5 hours without result. And I am new to IM. Can somebody tell me how to solve this and remove the margin?

Also I would like to repair name of file from e.g. map.pdf to map.jpg Now it result in map.pdf.jpg

Comment: I have the command almost done. I did a batch file for DOS Windows, with this command: for /r %%x in (*.pdf) do ^
convert -density 400 -shave "30%x30%" -quality 34%% "%%x" "%%x.jpg" .... only problem is that I don't know how to pass sign of percentage into the -shave command, to get it valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this code to crop the image after conversion to raster:

```
for /r %x in (*.pdf) do convert -density 400 -shave 1600x1600 -quality 34% "%x" "%x.jpg"
```